# Project Server 2013 - How to deploy one pwa instance with more than one site collection?

Tags: 2013, project-server

I have different web applications for project sites. But when I attempt to create a new project site in Operational Policies – Connected SharePoint Sites, I cannot change the default web application, I attempt to change the web application in project site provisioning settings but only I can see the default web application.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design behavior of Project Server. This feature is deprecated in Project Server 2013. It was there in Project Server 2010.